# Array.map is not a function (Array in localStorage)

Tags: reactjs

Array.map is not a function (Array in localStorage) in React

It was confirmed that it was an array in the console log.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iut01.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVOaV.png)

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do `JSON.parse` before map:

```
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workList')).map((a, i) => {
```